# LinearGradient not throwing any errors but not rendering

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

I have a rather deeply nested component with a `<LinearGradient>` wrapper around the entire thing. I made sure its properly installed and imported from expo, so no errors and the component renders, just with no Linear Gradient above it. The code is as follows, NOTE that the colors are `'black'` and `'white'` for testing, but eventually `'white'` will be changed with a transparent value

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native';
import { LandingStyles } from '../../Styles/LandingPageStyles';
import LandingPageContainer from './LandingComponents/LandingPageContainer';
import Title from './LandingComponents/Title';

import backgroundImage from '../../assets/loginBackground.png'
import {LinearGradient} from 'expo-linear-gradient';



const LandingPage = ({ handleLoggedIn }) => {
    return (
        <LinearGradient colors={['black' ,'white']} start={{x: 0.5, y: 1 }} end={{x: 0.5, y: 0.7 }} style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={LandingStyles.container}>
                <ImageBackground style={LandingStyles.backdrop} source={backgroundImage} resizeMode="cover">
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.4) !important',}}>
                            <View style={LandingStyles.titleIcon}>
                                <Title />
                            </View>
                            <LandingPageContainer handleLoggedIn={handleLoggedIn} />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        </LinearGradient>
    );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I realised that we both have flex:1, when I removed it, it was fixed. So Lineargradient does not work with flex: 1. You need to apply a width and height on 100% style:

```
<LinearGradient 
    colors={['black' ,'white']} 
    start={{x: 0.5, y: 1 }} 
    end={{x: 0.5, y: 0.7 }} 
    style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        …
</LinearGradient>
```